# Can't define function on user-defined data-type

Tags: haskell

I'm following a tutorial and have the following type definitions:

```
data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)
data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Point Point deriving (Show)
```

Loading the file with these definitions into ghci, and wanting to define a function, using

```
surface :: Shape -> Float
```

I get the error message *Variable not in scope: surface :: Shape -> Float*.

I don't even see where I do have a variable, let alone why I get this error! Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you entering that line in GHCi? If so, don't. Write you code in a .hs file, and then load that file in GHCi. If you enter `surface :: Type` in GHCi, you are asking it to evaluate `surface`, as if it were already defined, much like writing `[] :: [Int]` or `Nothing :: Maybe String` or `id 5 :: Double`. (You could also use multiline input mode in GHCi, but using a file is simpler.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GHCi finds the type signature for `surface` but can't parse the file because there's no body for that function. In Haskell functions cannot be declared but undefined.

If you still need to load your file you can add `surface = undefined`

```
data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)
data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Point Point deriving (Show)

surface :: Shape -> Float
surface = undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Use multiline input in `ghci`

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| surface :: Shape -> Float
Prelude| surface = undefined
Prelude| :}
```